# Issue with Eclipse Indigo R1 and Android Emulator on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, emulation, eclipse-indigo

I have an unusual problem with Eclipse Indigo R1 and the Android SDK Emulator which appears specific to Windows 7.

I use Windows 7 32-bit and I decided to have a look at Android development. I've already been using Eclipse for other stuff so I downloaded the Android SDK, etc and set it up without any difficulty.

Next if I create the obligatory Hello World project, run it on the emulator, it will work fine... a bit slow starting up (as expected) but it runs.

If I then change the source and try to re-run it on the emulator, nothing happens. I get a green progress bar about quarterways across Eclipse in the Taskbar and thats about it. It just sits there indefinitely. No warnings, messages or anything else. If I close down Eclipse and start it up again, it will work perfectly but just for the first run and then back to the same again.

I've tried all sorts of stuff, including different avds, reinstalling Eclipse and the Android SDK. I've even tried moving the Android SDK down to the root of the drive to eliminate any possibility of a space in the path causing the problem. Nothing works.

Next step was to repeat the installation on a Windows XP machine and it works perfectly every time. I can edit and re-run no problem at all but it will not work on Windows 7.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening or how I can get around it? It's driving me nuts at this stage.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the build output log to verbose in Eclipse preferences for Android?
Maybe that will give you a clue?

Comment: No, nothing further. It just says 'Launching delegate' and it sticks at 27%